# CSS on webkit browsers - elements not positioned correct sometimes

Tags: html, css

I have a small website that i tested on IE,FF and it seems to work fine.
when i try it on chrome or safari some of the elements get positioned in the wrong place - but only some of the time. this happens around 50% of the time (5 out of 10 refreshes).
these are the elements and related CSS:

```
<div id="ctl00_mainFormPlacHolder_incidentsList" class="incidentsList">
   <a href="ManageUserTasks.aspx?IncidentID=7">
      <div class="incident lightBackgroundMarginBottom completed" runat="server" onserverclick="incidentClicked">
         <div class="incidentName"> All Completed Incident </div>
         <div class="incidentDateTime"> <span>8/12/2013 | 08:42</span> </div>
      </div> 
   </a>
</div>

.incidentsList {
max-height: 820px;
overflow-y: auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
}

.incidentsList a {
text-decoration: none;
}

.incident {
width: 100%;
height: 64px;
line-height: 64px;
}

.incidentName {
height: 100%;
width: 50%;
text-align: left;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
display: inline-block;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
margin-left: 10px;
}

.incidentDateTime {
height: 100%;
width: 40%;
text-align: end;
float: right;
margin-right: 10px;
}
```

as you can see what i want to have is a line (.incident) with 100% width, and in it on the left i should have some text (.incidentName) and on the right side some other text (.incidentDateTime).

- i have several lines, but even with a single line i get the same problem -
  what happens is that sometimes the right side text (.incidentDateTime) is displayed exactly 1 line below where it should be.

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: The **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LSEZN/)**

Comment: I simply give the demo for people who wants to look at the issue. I don't see any problem here. Just the right text displaying under when the width of the window is too low. This is an expected behaviour. There might be some more CSS/HTML that causes this.

Comment: Try changing `margin-right` and `margin-left` to `padding` and using the `box-sizing: border-box` property on you two classes.

Answer (score 0):

well I think its the cascading effect, like when the content on either of the div gets a bit larger, the div containing it grows since its in percentages, and maybe giving a "max-width" property to both the adjacent divs shall make it concrete.

Comment: if that is the case then why does it happen only some of the time? (using the same content)

Comment: well everytime I tried it worked flawless, so I couldnt recreate the problem you are having, and last but not the least, try disabling any addons like "adblockplus" or something, because most of the times they mess with our elements and are actually hard to guess that they are the actual culprit.